# Optimizing join in vertica

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I hava a query like this

```
SELECT a.column, b.column
FROM
table_a a INNER JOIN tableb_b ON
a.id= b.id
where a.anotherid = 'some condition'
```

It is supposed to be very fast because with the predicate a.anotherid = 'some condition' the query plan should filter much data on table_b.
However, according to the document of [Vertica](https://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/15164.htm),

> The WHERE clause is evaluated **after** the join is performed. It filters
>   records returned by the FROM clause, eliminating any records that do
>   not satisfy the WHERE clause condition.

Which is mean the query will do the join first and then filtering, which is very slow, this is also showed in the query plan

[image]

So, is there any way to push the filter before the join?
Or is there any other way to optimize the query?

Comment: Simply do ON
a.id= b.id
AND a.anotherid = 'some condition'?

Comment: that's is what it is now, if you look the query

Comment: I still see a WHERE clause...

Comment: SELECT a.column, b.column
FROM
table_a a INNER JOIN tableb_b ON
a.id= b.id
and a.anotherid = 'some condition'   still don't work, : (

Comment: Any difference performance-wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The `EXPLAIN` shows `NO STATISTICS`. These need to be [updated](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/ANALYZE_STATISTICS.htm).
2. Vertica will optimize the predicate in this case using SIP:

> Sideways Information Passing (SIP) has been effective in improving join performance by filtering data as early as possible in the plan. It can be thought of as an advanced variation of predicate push down since the join is being used to do filtering [27]. For example, consider a HashJoin that joins two tables using simple equality predicates. The HashJoin will first create a hash table from the inner input before it starts reading data from the outer input to do the join. Special SIP filters are built during optimizer planning and placed in the Scan operator. At run time, the Scan has access to the Join’s hash table and the SIP filters are used to evaluate whether the outer key values exist in the hash table. Rows that do not pass these filters are not output by the Scan thus increaseing performance since we are not unnecessarily bringing the data through the plan only to be filtered away later by the join.

For example:

```
SELECT a.online_page_key
FROM   online_sales.online_sales_fact a
       JOIN online_sales.online_page_dimension b
         ON b.online_page_key = a.online_page_key
WHERE  b.page_type = 'quarterly';
```

Will produce the same plan as:

```
SELECT a.online_page_key 
FROM   online_sales.online_sales_fact a 
       JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM   online_sales.online_page_dimension 
             WHERE  page_type = 'quarterly') b 
         ON b.online_page_key = a.online_page_key;
```

Which looks like:

```
 Access Path:
 +-JOIN HASH [Cost: 14K, Rows: 988K] (PATH ID: 1)
 |  Join Cond: (online_page_dimension.online_page_key = a.online_page_key)
 | +-- Outer -> STORAGE ACCESS for a [Cost: 12K, Rows: 5M] (PATH ID: 2)
 | |      Projection: online_sales.online_sales_fact_super
 | |      Materialize: a.online_page_key
 | |      Runtime Filter: (SIP1(HashJoin): a.online_page_key)
 | +-- Inner -> STORAGE ACCESS for online_page_dimension [Cost: 36, Rows: 198] (PATH ID: 3)
 | |      Projection: online_sales.online_page_dimension_super
 | |      Materialize: online_page_dimension.online_page_key
 | |      Filter: (online_page_dimension.page_type = 'quarterly')
```

3. Most times, a hash join is sufficient. If you want to improve for a merge join, see my post on [optimizing for merge join](http://vertica.tips/2014/10/20/spill-to-disk-optimizing-for-merge-join/).

Comment: that is really helpful, after analyzing the table, the database successfully push down the filter. If i need to improve the  performance further, will changing the hash join to merge join help? Do you have any article about this topic? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JadeTang Not necessarily. Follow the link to my blog post at the bottom of the answer. *"A merge join will always be more efficient than a hash join, but not necessarily faster. If the data set is small, it’s possible that a hash join can process faster. "*